# How to update a record with prompt.(If null don't update)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, sqlplus, nvl

I'm creating a script where I need a prompt to come up asking to update the record if I input something, if I leave it null I want to not update. 
Anyways I figure it has something to do with CASE,or NVL.

The first part asks for a number. After I input the number it gives me info on STR_NUM. Then another prompt(the part I need help with) is supposed to come up asking if I want to change the name(STR_NAME). If I leave the prompt blank then nothing changes, however if I input in something it should change the STR_NAME.

```
ACCEPT v_str_num NUMBER FORMAT 999 PROMPT 'Enter store number:'      

SELECT 
    'Store Name: ' || '' || STR_Name || '' || CHR(13) ||   CHR(10) ||  
'Quantity: ' || '' || STR_QTY || ''  
FROM STR 
WHERE STR_NUM = &v_STR_NUM;

UPDATE STR
SET STR_NAME = NVL((PROMPT ACCEPT CHAR v_str_name), STR_NAME)
WHERE STR_NUM = &v_str_num;
```

However I can't get a prompt to appear at all. Am I supposed to incorporate a select and update statement together somehow?

**EDIT:**  Ok I've been just messing around. I think I might be closer because atleast I got the prompt but I get a missing expression error for the update part.Since it will store in v_str_name, it may be possible if I call it down there I can do it that way(idk I'm still new).

```
ACCEPT v_str_name CHAR FORMAT A20 Prompt 'Enter something '

SELECT 
'Update NAME' || '' ||                                                       
 (UPDATE STR 
 SET STR_NAME = NVL('&v_str_name',STR_NAME)
 WHERE STR_NUM = &v_str_num) || ''  
FROM STR;
```

**EDIT 2:** I GOT IT. It's easier then I thought it would be.

```
ACCEPT v_str_name CHAR FORMAT A20 Prompt 'TYPE NEW NAME OR LEAVE BLANK TO KEEP CURRENT'

UPDATE STR 
SET STR_NAME = (SELECT NVL('&v_str_name', STR_NAME)
FROM STR 
WHERE STR_NUM = &v_str_num)
WHERE STR_NUM = &v_str_num;
```

Comment: Which SQL tool or server are you using? Prompts are not a part of standard SQL, but various products include ways to do prompts in a batch of SQL that will run at the command line. For example, Oracle's SQLPlus command line interface does this (or used to when I used it), but the details are very specific to Oracle. The answer is going to depend on which product you are using.

Comment: Well the end product(script) needs to be compatible with SQL Plus.